# Connecting Apache Superset to an external database

Tags: database, postgresql, sqlalchemy, apache-superset

I am running apache superset on docker, and I have been trying to connect to an external database(Postgres) using the example link on SQLAlchemy Docs for connecting to a Postgres database (**postgresql://scott:tiger@localhost/mydatabase** // postgresql://username:password@localhost:5433/postgres). However, I have been getting the following error: Connection failed, please check your connection settings. Could someone please help me with this.

Comment: Inspect the permitted connections in the `pg_hba.conf` file on the server machine.

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure that your postgres is on the same network (localhost)?  It seems for external database, that it would likely be on another network (and therefore you would use IP address)?

If these are the docs you are looking at --> https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/12/core/engines.html#database-urls

Then you might want to think in terms of 'host', meaning then an IP(v4) address and/or DNS.

Answer (score 0):

As it was recommended you may need to whitelist your Superset IP address in pg_hba.conf.

You may also need to check if you have the right driver installed in the docker instance that you are running superset.